# How do I set up my own ldap in laravel

Tags: ldap, laravel-5.4, postman, adldap

The existing ldap is only used for authentication. For the application that I created, for example authentication is successful then the user will be able to enter into the system. If not successful then the error message will appear. 
How do I set up my own ldap in laravel. with postman and token?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, avoid using LDAP :)

Having said that, try this small tutorial:

[laravel-simple-ldap-auth](https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/laravel-simple-ldap-auth)

You will have to ask your IT administrator for the real connection data of your production LDAP server.